ADO Terraform Pipeline. VM in one subscription, DNS record in another subscription
I'm pretty new to creating pipelines with ADO and need some artistic advice.
I have a pipeline that creates a virtual machine in Azure in my 'subscription-A'.  As a step in this process I'd like to create an 'A RECORD' in my DNS, but my DNS lives in 'subscription-B'.
Maybe the best way is to have a separate 'DNS-pipeline' that only is responsible for creating records, but logically it seems to make sense that a single pipeline should be able to complete this setup in one swoop.
Right now my virtual-machine-terraform-yaml is called like this:
    - task: TerraformCLI@0
      displayName: 'Terraform Init'
      inputs:
        command: init
        workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/terraform'
        backendType: azurerm
        backendServiceArm: sc-my-vm-subscription-A

I could create a second terraform directory, and a second service connection for the DNS subscription,  hypothetically my git repo for the DNS work and my yaml would look like this:
    - task: TerraformCLI@0
      displayName: 'Terraform Init'
      inputs:
        command: init
        workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/terraform'
        backendType: azurerm
        backendServiceArm: sc-gypsy-150dev

    - task: TerraformCLI@0
      displayName: 'Terraform Init'
      inputs:
        command: init
        workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/terraform-dns'
        backendType: azurerm
        backendServiceArm: sc-DNS-subscription-B

This Azure layout is for my home projects.  Things are much more complicated at the office.    Maybe someone has some awesome home lab blueprints for Azure/ADO?  I'm trying to find the most simple and clean layout.  Thanks for any input.
-Scott
I've been hunting around in various postings but nothing I found covered this point.

Deploy two subscription related resources in one azure devops pipeline ? I think your pipeline yaml pattern should works well.

Based on your description, your workflow is acceptable, and we can create different pipelines to deploy terraform templates under different paths from 1 repo. If you would prefer, please note that we are also able to deploy resources in the terraform templates into different Azure subscriptions within one single pipeline.
Taking your scenario for example, we have 2 terraform templates in the 2 folders of your repo and we need to run the terraform init (-> terraform validate -> terraform plan ->) terraform apply commands twice, each time within one of the two folders by setting the task property of workingDirectory and we can use different Azure Resource Manager service connections to decide the target subscriptions for deployment.

As an optimization, if you have purchased multiple pipeline parallel jobs, you may consider deploying the two templates simultaneously via 2 agent jobs. Here is a sample YAML pipeline for your reference.
Image
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  ARMSvcCnnSubA: ARMSvcCnnAutoSub7
  backendStateRgA: rg-azstorageaccount
  backendStateStorageA: storageaccounta
  backendStatecontainerA: containertf

  ARMSvcCnnSubB: ARMSvcCnnAutoSub8
  backendStateRgB: rg-azstorageaccount
  backendStateStorageB: storageaccountb
  backendStatecontainerB: containertf

jobs:
- job: TFDeploymentToSubA
  steps:
  - task: TerraformInstaller@2
    inputs:
      terraformVersion: 'latest'
    displayName: Install Terraform on MS-hosted agent
  - task: TerraformCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: 'init'
      workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Terraform-DeployToSubA'
      backendType: 'azurerm'
      backendServiceArm: '$(ARMSvcCnnSubA)' # Save the backend state file in the storage account from SubA
      backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: '$(backendStateRgA)'
      backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: '$(backendStateStorageA)'
      backendAzureRmContainerName: '$(backendStatecontainerA)'
      backendAzureRmKey: 'deploytosuba.tfstate'
      allowTelemetryCollection: true
    displayName: Terraform init
  - task: TerraformCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: 'validate'
      workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Terraform-DeployToSubA'
      allowTelemetryCollection: true
    displayName: Terraform validate
  - task: TerraformCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: 'plan'
      workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Terraform-DeployToSubA'
      environmentServiceName: '$(ARMSvcCnnSubA)'
      commandOptions: '-input=false -var "RGNAME=subA-rg-tfdemo-$(Build.BuildId)"'
      allowTelemetryCollection: true
    displayName: Terraform plan
  - task: TerraformCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: 'apply'
      workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Terraform-DeployToSubA'
      environmentServiceName: '$(ARMSvcCnnSubA)'
      commandOptions: '-input=false -var "RGNAME=subA-rg-tfdemo-$(Build.BuildId)"'
      allowTelemetryCollection: true
    displayName: Terraform apply

- job: TFDeploymentToSubB
  steps:
  - task: TerraformInstaller@2
    inputs:
      terraformVersion: 'latest'
    displayName: Install Terraform on MS-hosted agent
  - task: TerraformCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: 'init'
      workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Terraform-DeployToSubB'
      backendType: 'azurerm'
      backendServiceArm: '$(ARMSvcCnnSubB)' # Save the backend state file in the storage account from SubA
      backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: '$(backendStateRgB)'
      backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: '$(backendStateStorageB)'
      backendAzureRmContainerName: '$(backendStatecontainerB)'
      backendAzureRmKey: 'deploytosubb.tfstate'
      allowTelemetryCollection: true
    displayName: Terraform init
  - task: TerraformCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: 'validate'
      workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Terraform-DeployToSubB'
      allowTelemetryCollection: true
    displayName: Terraform validate
  - task: TerraformCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: 'plan'
      workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Terraform-DeployToSubB'
      environmentServiceName: '$(ARMSvcCnnSubB)'
      commandOptions: '-input=false -var "RGNAME=subB-rg-tfdemo-$(Build.BuildId)"'
      allowTelemetryCollection: true
    displayName: Terraform plan
  - task: TerraformCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: 'apply'
      workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Terraform-DeployToSubB'
      environmentServiceName: '$(ARMSvcCnnSubB)'
      commandOptions: '-input=false -var "RGNAME=subB-rg-tfdemo-$(Build.BuildId)"'
      allowTelemetryCollection: true
    displayName: Terraform apply




